# Sorting a Dataframe created with sapply using R

Tags: r

I created an array counting the NAs of every column using sapply

```
na_count <-sapply(df, function(y) sum(length(which(is.na(y)))))
```

Then I transformed it into a Dataframe

```
na_count <-data.frame(na_count)
```

I'm trying to sort it in a descending order using the following code:

```
na_count[order(na_count$na_count),]
```

It does work, however I lose the column that has the name of each feature. How can I sort it without losing those names?

Comment: check out `arrange` from the `dplyr` package

Comment: Why not do everything in one line: `df[order(sapply(df, function(y) sum(length(which(is.na(y))))), decreasing = T)]`; no need to convert `na_count` into a `data.frame`; the output of `sapply` is a `vector` which we `order` and directly use for re-arranging the columns of `df`.

Comment: How about: `sort(colSums(is.na(df)))`? And since you said descending, you may want `sort(colSums(is.na(df)), decreasing = TRUE)` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked as a charm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are stored as `row.names`, which are stored as an *attribute* in the object and therefore easily discarded by functions. (I should note that I do *not* lose the row name with your code, but that doesn't change the fact that they are fragile, and many programmers believe that if you need to keep it, explicitly make it a row name.) Most functions within `dplyr` and related packages, for instance, advertise discarding them intentionally.

It's often best to explicitly make them a column. Adding in @MauritsEvers's and @JasonAizkalns' suggestions, perhaps something like:

```
na_count <- sort(colSums(is.na(df)))
na_count <- data.frame(names=names(na_count), count=na_count)
```

(It is currently sorted from least-to-most `NA` counts.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I notice it stored the names somewhere but I had no idea it was stored as an attribute. I will definitely use that in the future.